# How to optimize an indirect radix sort? (a.k.a. how to optimize unpredictable memory access patterns)

Tags: c++, optimization, radix-sort

I've written an indirect radix sort algorithm in C++ (by indirect, I mean it returns the indices of the items):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template<class It1, class It2>
void radix_ipass(
    It1 begin, It1 const end,
    It2 const a, size_t const i,
    std::vector<std::vector<size_t> > &buckets)
{
    size_t ncleared = 0;
    for (It1 j = begin; j != end; ++j)
    {
        size_t const k = a[*j][i];
        while (k >= ncleared && ncleared < buckets.size())
        { buckets[ncleared++].clear(); }
        if (k >= buckets.size())
        {
            buckets.resize(k + 1);
            ncleared = buckets.size();
        }
        buckets[k].push_back(size_t());
        using std::swap; swap(buckets[k].back(), *j);
    }
    for (std::vector<std::vector<size_t> >::iterator
        j = buckets.begin(); j != buckets.begin() + ncleared; j->clear(), ++j)
    {
        begin = std::swap_ranges(j->begin(), j->end(), begin);
    }
}

template<class It, class It2>
void radix_isort(It const begin, It const end, It2 const items)
{
    for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i != end - begin; ++i) { items[i] = i; }
    size_t smax = 0;
    for (It i = begin; i != end; ++i)
    {
        size_t const n = i->size();
        smax = n > smax ? n : smax;
    }
    std::vector<std::vector<size_t> > buckets;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != smax; ++i)
    {
        radix_ipass(
            items, items + (end - begin),
            begin, smax - i - 1, buckets);
    }
}
```

It seems to perform around 40% faster than `std::sort` when I test it with the following code (3920 ms compared to 6530 ms):

```
#include <functional>

template<class Key>
struct key_comp : public Key
{
    explicit key_comp(Key const &key = Key()) : Key(key) { }
    template<class T>
    bool operator()(T const &a, T const &b) const
    { return this->Key::operator()(a) < this->Key::operator()(b); }
};

template<class Key>
key_comp<Key> make_key_comp(Key const &key) { return key_comp<Key>(key); }

template<class T1, class T2>
struct add : public std::binary_function<T1, T2, T1>
{ T1 operator()(T1 a, T2 const &b) const { return a += b; } };

template<class F>
struct deref : public F
{
    deref(F const &f) : F(f) { }
    typename std::iterator_traits<
        typename F::result_type
    >::value_type const
        &operator()(typename F::argument_type const &a) const
    { return *this->F::operator()(a); }
};

template<class T> deref<T> make_deref(T const &t) { return deref<T>(t); }

size_t xorshf96(void)  // random number generator
{
    static size_t x = 123456789, y = 362436069, z = 521288629;
    x ^= x << 16;
    x ^= x >> 5;
    x ^= x << 1;
    size_t t = x;
    x = y;
    y = z;
    z = t ^ x ^ y;
    return z;
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <array>

int main(void)
{
    typedef std::vector<std::array<size_t, 3> > Items;
    Items items(1 << 24);
    std::vector<size_t> ranks(items.size() * 2);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != items.size(); i++)
    {
        ranks[i] = i;
        for (size_t j = 0; j != items[i].size(); j++)
        { items[i][j] = xorshf96() & 0xFFF; }
    }
    clock_t const start = clock();
    if (1) { radix_isort(items.begin(), items.end(), ranks.begin()); }
    else  // STL sorting
    {
        std::sort(
            ranks.begin(),
            ranks.begin() + items.size(),
            make_key_comp(make_deref(std::bind1st(
                add<Items::const_iterator, ptrdiff_t>(),
                items.begin()))));
    }
    printf("%u ms\n",
        (unsigned)((clock() - start) * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC),
        std::min(ranks.begin(), ranks.end()));
    return 0;
}
```

Hmm, I guess that's the best I can do, I thought.

But after lots of banging my head against the wall, I realized that prefetching in the beginning of `radix_ipass` can help cut down the result to **1440 ms** (!):

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>

...

    for (It1 j = begin; j != end; ++j)
    {
#if defined(_MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS)  // should be defined if xmmintrin.h is included
        enum { N = 8 };
        if (end - j > N)
        { _mm_prefetch((char const *)(&a[j[N]][i]), _MM_HINT_T0); }
#endif
        ...
    }
```

Clearly, the bottleneck is the memory bandwidth---the access pattern is unpredictable.

#### So now my question is: what else can I do to make it even faster on similar amounts of data?

Or is there not much room left for improvement?

(I'm hoping to avoid compromising the readability of the code if possible, so if the readability is harmed, the improvement should be significant.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I'm not asking for anyone to "review" my code though. This is an optimization question, not a code review request.

Comment: You might want to reads [what's on topic on codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "If you are looking for feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project in the following areas... Performance... then you are in the right place!"

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I think this question is a lot more similar to the types of performances questions you see on StackOverflow than to the types you see on CodeReview.SE.

Comment: There seems to be some output missing from the final `printf` (more arguments than formatting specifiers). Also, I find `make_key_comp(..)` rather hard to read and reason about. In C++11, I'd use a lambda; otherwise a custom function object. This doesn't affect performance, though (I tested). `size_t` requires `<cstddef>` (+ `using std::size_t;`). I don't quite understand why you use `size_t` as the value type when you only store 12 bit of information: `xorshf96() & 0xFFF` (switching to a 16-bit int improves the `std::sort` performance slightly).

Comment: @DyP: lol like I said, I wasn't looking for a code review! =P The final printf argument is just to make sure the compiler doesn't optimize it away, I didn't actually want to print it. The lambda I don't care about, this was part of a larger piece of code I took out and I didn't want to use lambdas there. Like you said it doesn't make a performance difference so I just kept it this way. And yes, using a 16-bit int would improve performance *slightly* but that's not interesting to me here -- I'm looking for big improvements, not small ones.

Comment: That wasn't meant as a code review ;) just a hint for anyone who wants to try that code. "The final printf argument is just to make sure the compiler doesn't optimize it away" Yeah, but I'm not sure if it forces the compiler if you don't *actually* print it (well, we see the time consumption). The actual reason why I'm writing is that it might be possible to get a speed-up of factor 2.7 for `std::sort` by using a non-inplace algorithm, packing together ranks and values in a single data structure (confirmed for `2<<22` elements, even including the additional copies & allocations in the timing).

Comment: @DyP: Ooh interesting, I didn't think packing the data together would help! Would you mind posting it as an answer? That's exactly the type of thing I'm looking for :)

Comment: I haven't checked yet if it produces correct results and only ran it in my VM -- you might be better off writing a version yourself and testing. When you've done testing I might have finished composing my answer and we could compare ;)

Comment: @DyP: Haha okay I'll try that. By the way, make sure you're actually doing the prefetching -- I forgot to mention `xmmintrin.h` has to be included, and `_MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS` is a better macro test for than what I was using before (`_MM_HINT_T0`).

Comment: @DyP: Wait, actually, I think I misunderstood what you said. Were you talking about speeding up `std::sort`? That's not interesting to me -- `std::sort` isn't even linear-time, so it's not always a substitute for radix sort. I just put it there for the sake of empirical comparison, that's all. My question is how to increase the speed of radix sort, not `std::sort`.

Comment: @Mehrdad Give it a fair comparison ;) first thing for me was to look at how to improve `std::sort`, I'll look at later at the radix sort tomorrow. I'll post it as a community wiki, as it's not an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using a more compact data structure that combines ranks and values can boost the performance of `std::sort` by a factor 2-3. Essentially, the sort now runs on a `vector<pair<Value,Rank>>`. The `Value` data type, `std::array<integer_type, 3>` has been replaced for this by a more compact `pair<uint32_t, uint8_t>` data structure. Only half a byte of it is unused, and the `<` comparison can by done in two steps, first using a presumably efficient comparison of `uint32_t`s (it's not clear if the loop used by `std::array<..>::operator<` can be optimized to a similarly fast code, but the replacement of `std::array<integer_type,3>` by this data structure yielded another performance boost).

Still, it doesn't get as efficient as the radix sort. (Maybe you could tweak a custom QuickSort with prefetches?)

Besides that additional sorting method, I've replaced the `xorshf96` by a `mt19937`, because I know how to provide a seed for the latter ;)

The seed and the number of values can be changed via two command-line arguments: first the seed, then the count.

Compiled with g++ 4.9.0 20131022, using `-std=c++11 -march=native -O3`, for a 64-bit linux

Sample runs; **important note** running on a Core2Duo processor U9400 (old & slow!)

```
item count: 16000000
using std::sort
duration: 12260 ms
result sorted: true

seed: 5648
item count: 16000000
using std::sort
duration: 12230 ms
result sorted: true

seed: 5648
item count: 16000000
using std::sort
duration: 12230 ms
result sorted: true


seed: 5648
item count: 16000000
using std::sort with a packed data structure
duration: 4290 ms
result sorted: true

seed: 5648
item count: 16000000
using std::sort with a packed data structure
duration: 4270 ms
result sorted: true

seed: 5648
item count: 16000000
using std::sort with a packed data structure
duration: 4280 ms
result sorted: true


item count: 16000000
using radix sort
duration: 3790 ms
result sorted: true

seed: 5648
item count: 16000000
using radix sort
duration: 3820 ms
result sorted: true

seed: 5648
item count: 16000000
using radix sort
duration: 3780 ms
result sorted: true
```

New or changed code:

```
template<class It>
struct fun_obj
{
        It beg;
        bool operator()(ptrdiff_t lhs, ptrdiff_t rhs)
        {
                return beg[lhs] < beg[rhs];
        }
};

template<class It>
fun_obj<It> make_fun_obj(It beg)
{
        return fun_obj<It>{beg};
}

struct uint32p8_t
{
        uint32_t m32;
        uint8_t m8;

        uint32p8_t(std::array<uint16_t, 3> const& a)
                : m32( a[0]<<(32-3*4) | a[1]<<(32-2*3*4) | (a[2]&0xF00)>>8)
                , m8( a[2]&0xFF )
        {
        }

        operator std::array<size_t, 3>() const
        {
                return {{m32&0xFFF00000 >> (32-3*4), m32&0x000FFF0 >> (32-2*3*4),
                         (m32&0xF)<<8 | m8}};
        }

        friend bool operator<(uint32p8_t const& lhs, uint32p8_t const& rhs)
        {
                if(lhs.m32 < rhs.m32) return true;
                if(lhs.m32 > rhs.m32) return false;
                return lhs.m8 < rhs.m8;
        }
};

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <random>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);

    constexpr auto items_count_default = 2<<22;
    constexpr auto seed_default = 42;

    uint32_t const seed = argc > 1 ? std::atoll(argv[1]) : seed_default;
    std::cout << "seed: " << seed << "\n";

    size_t const items_count = argc > 2 ? std::atoll(argv[2])
                                        : items_count_default;
    std::cout << "item count: " << items_count << "\n";

    using Items_array_value_t =
        #ifdef RADIX_SORT
            size_t
        #elif defined(STDSORT)
            uint16_t
        #elif defined(STDSORT_PACKED)
            uint16_t
        #endif
    ;

    typedef std::vector<std::array<Items_array_value_t, 3> > Items;
    Items items(items_count);

    auto const ranks_count =
        #ifdef RADIX_SORT
            items.size() * 2
        #elif defined(STDSORT)
            items.size()
        #elif defined(STDSORT_PACKED)
            items.size()
    #endif
    ;

    //auto prng = xorshf96;
    std::mt19937 gen(seed);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist;
    auto prng = [&dist, &gen]{return dist(gen);};

    std::vector<size_t> ranks(ranks_count);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != items.size(); i++)
    {
        ranks[i] = i;

        for (size_t j = 0; j != items[i].size(); j++)
        { items[i][j] = prng() & 0xFFF; }
    }

    std::cout << "using ";
    clock_t const start = clock();
    #ifdef RADIX_SORT
        std::cout << "radix sort\n";
        radix_isort(items.begin(), items.end(), ranks.begin());
    #elif defined(STDSORT)
        std::cout << "std::sort\n";
        std::sort(ranks.begin(), ranks.begin() + items.size(),
                  make_fun_obj(items.cbegin())
                  //make_key_comp(make_deref(std::bind1st(
                  //    add<Items::const_iterator, ptrdiff_t>(),
                  //    items.begin())))
                 );
    #elif defined(STDSORT_PACKED)
        std::cout << "std::sort with a packed data structure\n";
        using Items_ranks = std::vector< std::pair<uint32p8_t,
                                         decltype(ranks)::value_type> >;
        Items_ranks items_ranks;

        size_t i = 0;
        for(auto iI = items.cbegin(); iI != items.cend(); ++iI, ++i)
        {
            items_ranks.emplace_back(*iI, i);
        }

        std::sort(begin(items_ranks), end(items_ranks),
                  [](Items_ranks::value_type const& lhs,
                     Items_ranks::value_type const& rhs)
                  { return lhs.first < rhs.first; }
                 );
        std::transform(items_ranks.cbegin(), items_ranks.cend(), begin(ranks),
                       [](Items_ranks::value_type const& e) { return e.second; }
                      );
    #endif
    auto const duration = (clock() - start) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000);

    bool const sorted = std::is_sorted(ranks.begin(), ranks.begin() + items.size(),
                                       make_fun_obj(items.cbegin()));

    std::cout << "duration: " << duration << " ms\n"
              << "result sorted: " << std::boolalpha << sorted << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Full code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

#include <cstddef>
using std::size_t;
using std::ptrdiff_t;

#include <xmmintrin.h>

template<class It1, class It2>
void radix_ipass(
    It1 begin, It1 const end,
    It2 const a, size_t const i,
    std::vector<std::vector<size_t> > &buckets)
{
    size_t ncleared = 0;
    for (It1 j = begin; j != end; ++j)
    {
        #if defined(_MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS)
            constexpr auto N = 8;
            if(end - j > N)
            { _mm_prefetch((char const *)(&a[j[N]][i]), _MM_HINT_T0); }
        #else
            #error SS intrinsic not found
        #endif

        size_t const k = a[*j][i];
        while (k >= ncleared && ncleared < buckets.size())
        { buckets[ncleared++].clear(); }
        if (k >= buckets.size())
        {
            buckets.resize(k + 1);
            ncleared = buckets.size();
        }
        buckets[k].push_back(size_t());
        using std::swap; swap(buckets[k].back(), *j);
    }
    for (std::vector<std::vector<size_t> >::iterator
        j = buckets.begin(); j != buckets.begin() + ncleared; j->clear(), ++j)
    {
        begin = std::swap_ranges(j->begin(), j->end(), begin);
    }
}

template<class It, class It2>
void radix_isort(It const begin, It const end, It2 const items)
{
    for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i != end - begin; ++i) { items[i] = i; }
    size_t smax = 0;
    for (It i = begin; i != end; ++i)
    {
        size_t const n = i->size();
        smax = n > smax ? n : smax;
    }
    std::vector<std::vector<size_t> > buckets;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != smax; ++i)
    {
        radix_ipass(
            items, items + (end - begin),
            begin, smax - i - 1, buckets);
    }
}

#include <functional>

template<class Key>
struct key_comp : public Key
{
    explicit key_comp(Key const &key = Key()) : Key(key) { }
    template<class T>
    bool operator()(T const &a, T const &b) const
    { return this->Key::operator()(a) < this->Key::operator()(b); }
};

template<class Key>
key_comp<Key> make_key_comp(Key const &key) { return key_comp<Key>(key); }

template<class T1, class T2>
struct add : public std::binary_function<T1, T2, T1>
{ T1 operator()(T1 a, T2 const &b) const { return a += b; } };

template<class F>
struct deref : public F
{
    deref(F const &f) : F(f) { }
    typename std::iterator_traits<
        typename F::result_type
    >::value_type const
        &operator()(typename F::argument_type const &a) const
    { return *this->F::operator()(a); }
};

template<class T> deref<T> make_deref(T const &t) { return deref<T>(t); }

size_t xorshf96(void)  // random number generator
{
    static size_t x = 123456789, y = 362436069, z = 521288629;
    x ^= x << 16;
    x ^= x >> 5;
    x ^= x << 1;
    size_t t = x;
    x = y;
    y = z;
    z = t ^ x ^ y;
    return z;
}

template<class It>
struct fun_obj
{
        It beg;
        bool operator()(ptrdiff_t lhs, ptrdiff_t rhs)
        {
                return beg[lhs] < beg[rhs];
        }
};

template<class It>
fun_obj<It> make_fun_obj(It beg)
{
        return fun_obj<It>{beg};
}

struct uint32p8_t
{
        uint32_t m32;
        uint8_t m8;

        uint32p8_t(std::array<uint16_t, 3> const& a)
                : m32( a[0]<<(32-3*4) | a[1]<<(32-2*3*4) | (a[2]&0xF00)>>8)
                , m8( a[2]&0xFF )
        {
        }

        operator std::array<size_t, 3>() const
        {
                return {{m32&0xFFF00000 >> (32-3*4), m32&0x000FFF0 >> (32-2*3*4),
                         (m32&0xF)<<8 | m8}};
        }

        friend bool operator<(uint32p8_t const& lhs, uint32p8_t const& rhs)
        {
                if(lhs.m32 < rhs.m32) return true;
                if(lhs.m32 > rhs.m32) return false;
                return lhs.m8 < rhs.m8;
        }
};

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <random>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);

    constexpr auto items_count_default = 2<<22;
    constexpr auto seed_default = 42;

    uint32_t const seed = argc > 1 ? std::atoll(argv[1]) : seed_default;
    std::cout << "seed: " << seed << "\n";
    size_t const items_count = argc > 2 ? std::atoll(argv[2]) : items_count_default;
    std::cout << "item count: " << items_count << "\n";

    using Items_array_value_t =
        #ifdef RADIX_SORT
            size_t
        #elif defined(STDSORT)
            uint16_t
        #elif defined(STDSORT_PACKED)
            uint16_t
        #endif
    ;

    typedef std::vector<std::array<Items_array_value_t, 3> > Items;
    Items items(items_count);

    auto const ranks_count =
        #ifdef RADIX_SORT
            items.size() * 2
        #elif defined(STDSORT)
            items.size()
        #elif defined(STDSORT_PACKED)
            items.size()
    #endif
    ;

    //auto prng = xorshf96;
    std::mt19937 gen(seed);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist;
    auto prng = [&dist, &gen]{return dist(gen);};

    std::vector<size_t> ranks(ranks_count);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != items.size(); i++)
    {
        ranks[i] = i;

        for (size_t j = 0; j != items[i].size(); j++)
        { items[i][j] = prng() & 0xFFF; }
    }

    std::cout << "using ";
    clock_t const start = clock();
    #ifdef RADIX_SORT
        std::cout << "radix sort\n";
        radix_isort(items.begin(), items.end(), ranks.begin());
    #elif defined(STDSORT)
        std::cout << "std::sort\n";
        std::sort(ranks.begin(), ranks.begin() + items.size(),
                  make_fun_obj(items.cbegin())
                  //make_key_comp(make_deref(std::bind1st(
                  //    add<Items::const_iterator, ptrdiff_t>(),
                  //    items.begin())))
                 );
    #elif defined(STDSORT_PACKED)
        std::cout << "std::sort with a packed data structure\n";
        using Items_ranks = std::vector< std::pair<uint32p8_t,
                                         decltype(ranks)::value_type> >;
        Items_ranks items_ranks;

        size_t i = 0;
        for(auto iI = items.cbegin(); iI != items.cend(); ++iI, ++i)
        {
            items_ranks.emplace_back(*iI, i);
        }

        std::sort(begin(items_ranks), end(items_ranks),
                  [](Items_ranks::value_type const& lhs,
                     Items_ranks::value_type const& rhs)
                  { return lhs.first < rhs.first; }
                 );
        std::transform(items_ranks.cbegin(), items_ranks.cend(), begin(ranks),
                       [](Items_ranks::value_type const& e) { return e.second; }
                      );
    #endif
    auto const duration = (clock() - start) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000);

    bool const sorted = std::is_sorted(ranks.begin(), ranks.begin() + items.size(),
                                       make_fun_obj(items.cbegin()));

    std::cout << "duration: " << duration << " ms\n"
              << "result sorted: " << std::boolalpha << sorted << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```