# Using std::sort with custom sort object and data type template - Seeking correct syntax

Tags: c++, templates, sorting, struct

I try to make  std::sort with using my own comparison struct but I'm running into problems with templating types.

I have a std::vector of indices pointing into a data array, and I want to sort this list by the value of the array. This works fine for an array of known data type using the following:

```
struct SortByValue {
  double * src;
  SortByValue( double * srcP ){ src = srcP;}
  bool operator() (long i, long j) {return src[i]>src[j]; }
};

void MyClass::DoStuff(double * data){
  std::vector<ulong> myPointVec; 
  // [...] code filling myPointvec
  std::sort(myPointVec.begin(),myPointVec.end(),SortByValue(data));
};
```

However, now my data comes in different data types, and I've templated the DoStuff method as follows:

```
template <typename T> void MyClass::DoStuff(typename T * data){
  std::vector<ulong> myPointVec; 
  // [...] code filling myPointvec
  std::sort(myPointVec.begin(),myPointVec.end(),SortByValue(data));
};
```

The problem I have is, that I don't find the correct syntax to pass this templating on into my SortByValue struct (which needs to keep the pointer to the data of correct type.) I tried (and failed) with templating the struct too:

```
template <typename MT> 
struct SortByValue {
  MT * src;
  SortByValue( MT * srcP ){ src = srcP;}
  bool operator() (long i, long j) {return src[i]>src[j]; }
};

template <typename T> void MyClass::DoStuff(typename T * data){
  std::vector<ulong> myPointVec; 
  // [...] code filling myPointvec
  std::sort(myPointVec.begin(),myPointVec.end(),SortByValue((T *) data));
};
```

So how do I have to do this? Can someone post a code-example?

Comment: You can explicitly specify the type to be used as the template parameter by writing `SortByValue<T>(data)`. You should also mark the `operator()` as `const`, as the the `SortByValue` instance you create is a temporary and can't be passed by non-const reference.

Comment: Note you might get better performance by using a data structure that combines the indices and the values (because of caching). For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20012171/420683 (where it is compared to a radix sort)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should point template type of `SortByValue` and also `typename T*` is wrong construction, it cannot be compiled. It should be

```
template <typename MT> 
struct SortByValue {
  MT * src;
  SortByValue( MT * srcP ){ src = srcP;}
  bool operator() (long i, long j) {return src[i]>src[j]; }
};

template <typename T> void MyClass::DoStuff(T * data){
  std::vector<ulong> myPointVec; 
  // [...] code filling myPointvec
  std::sort(myPointVec.begin(),myPointVec.end(),SortByValue<T>(data));
};
```